# reading headers from multiple fits file from the same directory

Tags: python, file, header, fits

I'm very new to Python and I have no idea how to approach this!
I have a directory of FITS files, I want to be able to read a specific header from each of them and print them as a table.

I know how to construct the algorithm in English, and I also know how to read headers from individual FITS files, I just need help with doing it from a whole bunch in a directory.

1. First run `ls` and view all the files
2. Somehow construct a `for` loop telling python to go through each file of my directory and make it into a `hdulist`
3. Give the command of `hdulist[0].header['name of the header I want']` (looking at primary only)
4. Print all of them, possibly in an ASCII table or just a regular table/text file is fine.

Comment: The parts you don't understand are how to loop over the contents of a directory and how to pretty print the headers in a table?

Comment: The part I don't understand are how to do a for loop for getting header information for say 2 or 3 files at once....This is what I did to view everything:  

rootpath = '/Users/Arya/cbcd/'

pattern = '*.fits'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootpath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))

Comment: What do you hope the output will look like? Please edit your question to include the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
# yes, glob is your friend.
import glob
import os

# astropy is really your astro-friend.
# http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/index.html
from astropy.io import fits as pyfits
from astropy.table import Table, Column

# where is your data?
dir = "./"

# pick the header keys you want to dump to a table.
keys = ['NAXIS', 'RA', 'DEC', 'FILTER']
# pick the HDU you want to pull them from. It might be that your data are spectra, or FITS tables, or multi-extension "mosaics". 
hdu = 0

# get header keyword values
# http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html#working-with-a-fits-header
values = []
fitsNames = []
for fitsName in glob.glob(dir+'*.fits'):
    # opening the file is unnecessary. just pull the (right) header
    header = pyfits.getheader(fitsName, hdu)
    values.append([header.get(key) for key in keys])
    fitsNames.append(fitsName)
    # if you want the fits file name only without the full path then
    # fitsNames.append(os.path.split(fitsName)[1])

# Create a table container. 
# http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/construct_table.html
# One trick is to use the data types in the first "values" to let astropy guess datatypes.
# to use this trick, you need to specify the column names in the table
row0 = [dict(zip(keys, values[0]))]
t = Table(row0, names=keys)

# now add all the other rows. again, because dict didn't preserve column order, you have to repeat
# the dict here.
for i in range(1, len(values)):
    t.add_row(values[i])

# add the filenames column
#t.add_column
new_column = Column(name='fitsName', data=fitsNames)
t.add_column(new_column, 0)

# save the file
# http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/io.html
t.write('table.dat', format='ascii.ipac')
```

inline refs:

- http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/index.html
- http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html#working-with-a-fits-header
- http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/construct_table.html
- http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/io.html

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out! There is a problem however, I'm not able to create a table with the dict command. I get a value error stating the following: ValueError: Arguments "names" and "dtypes" must match number of columns [astropy.table.table] and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it! Thank you again!

Comment: so the "row0" command works, but the t=Table(row0, names=keys) command throws that error? i think i know what is wrong, but could you list which keys you are pulling from the header, @user3276219?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
# UNTESTED
import glob
import pyfits

for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
    hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
    print hdulist[0].header['name of the header I want']
    hdulist.close()
```

To print it as a table:

```
# UNTESTED
import glob
import pyfits

print "# FileName, Header"  
for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
    hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
    print fitsName, hdulist[0].header['name of the header I want']
    hdulist.close()
```

References:

- http://pythonhosted.org/pyfits/users_guide/users_tutorial.html
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html